# How to indent the fluent interface pattern "correctly" with eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, indentation

I just created a generator for some fluent interfaces. Now I have lots of code looking like this:

```
new MyFluentInterface()
    .setFirst( "first" )
    .setSecond( "second" )
    .setThird( "third" )
    .invoke( obj );
```

I like the indentation shown above, but I can't find a way to configure eclipse to indent this correctly.

eclipse always indents like this:

```
new MyFluentInterface()
.setFirst( "first" )
.setSecond( "second" )
.setThird( "third" )
.invoke( obj );
```

How can I configure eclipse so that it indents this fluent interface pattern as shown in my first code example?

Comment: Do you want the formatter to do that? I mean "CONTROL+SHIFT+f" on the whole buffer or do you want to be able to indent only that line?

Comment: It would be fine if either the formatter or the indenter of eclipse could produce this...

Comment: Hi, I know this is an old thread, have you noticed that `Ctrl+A`, `Ctrl+I` undoes this formatting?

Comment: This `Ctrl+I` thing is annoying as hell :)

Answer (score 74):

With Eclipse 3.6, this seems doable by configuring your custom **Java > Code Style > Formatter** profile. Edit it and go to the **Line Wrapping** tab and select **Function Call > Qualified invocations**. Then, in the **Settings for qualified invocations**, configure things like this:

[image]

This will (should) produce the expected result:

```
SomeEntity e1 = new SomeEntity.Builder()
    .age(10)
    .amount(10.0d)
    .firstname("foo")
    .lastname("bar")
    .build();
```

But this will obviously affect all the code, which I personally don't like. So I'm using the new [**Off/On Tags**](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.6-201006080911/eclipse-news-part2.html#JavaFormatter) from Eclipse 3.6 (last tab when editing a profile):

[image]

And enclose the parts that don't get formatted as I want and do it myself:

```
// @formatter:off
SomeEntity e2 = new SomeEntity.Builder()
    .age(10)
    .amount(10.0d)
    .firstname("foo")
    .lastname("bar")
    .build();
// @formatter:on
```

Pick your poison :)

Comment: @seanizer: Actually, the above is the result of the [Builder Pattern Eclipse Plugin](http://boss.bekk.no/bpep/). I like this little plugin as it is :)

Comment: This didn't work for me. Even after setting this up, the beginning of the "."-lines still match the beginning of the initial line

Comment: At first I didnt think this worked. I found out that it works with auto-format but adding "Correct indentation" to save actions overwrites and pulls it back. Im going to raise an eclipse bug.

Comment: I have show whitespace enabled (http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/249836/), and I use off/on tags to create a custom indentation for the different nestings (I'm using a Json builder).

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd you may want to try this one: https://code.google.com/p/fluent-builders-generator-eclipse-plugin/

Comment: If it doesn't work ensure there are no compile errors.  That stung me for weeks in Eclipse while sorting out formatting issues.