# How to set Eclipse code formatter to support fluent interfaces

Tags: java, eclipse, code-formatting

I've recently started working with an API that uses a "[fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)".  I'm struggling to find how to configure the Eclipse code formatter to support this properly.

What I want to get is this:

```
Foo myFoo = new Foo()
                  .setThis()
                  .setThat()
                  .setTheOther()
                  .setOneMoreThing();
```

but I can't hit on the right settings: I end up with something like this:

```
Foo myFoo = new Foo().setThis().setThat()
                  .setTheOther().setOneMoreThing();
```

which is nowhere near as readable.

Has anyone already solved this?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Sorry: turns out this is a near-duplicate of this: [How to indent the fluent interface pattern "correctly" with eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172937/how-to-indent-the-fluent-interface-pattern-correctly-with-eclipse?rq=1)

Here's the answer that worked for me:

The place to set this is on the "Line Wrapping" tab of the code formatting preferences page, in the "Qualified invocations" section of the "Function Calls" section.  The settings for what I wanted were:

Line wrapping policy: Wrap all element, except first element if not necessary

Indentation policy: Indent on column

[image]

Comment: Nicely work on Oxygen, thanks very much