# How to reduce indentation for complex pattern builder-like code in java with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

i am writting code following a builder pattern style using lambdas like the following example:

```
item.do1()
    .do2()
    .doIn((ItemIn itin)->{
        itin.do3()
            .do4()
            .doThere((Stuff stuf)->{
                stuf.do5()
                    .do6()
            }
    }
```

as you can see the indentation get very heavy for each function with lambda i use because there is a new level of indent for both the lambda scope and the pattern builder function chain.

so my question is the following, is there a way to disable/trick indent for function chains in Eclipse IDE?

for example:

```
item
.do1()
.do2()
.doIn((ItemIn itin)->{
    itin
    .do3()
    .do4()
    .doThere((Stuff stuf)->{
        stuf
        .do5()
        .do6()
    }
}
```

in a more common kind of code i guess it would be a bad idea but for this specific case i think it could really help

Edit: im mostly looking to see if it is possible on any version of Eclipse but if you have an answer and you know which version of Eclipse implemented it please let me know :)

Comment: You can play around with the values of *line wrapping* in *Preferences - Java - Code Style - Formatter* where you have profiles. Edit your current profile and apply default indentation of `1`, maybe...

Comment: Consider noting which version of Eclipse you are using as this may impact which preference parameters are available.

Comment: @deHaar i mean, im not trying to remove indentation in general, just in a specific case ( the pattern builder function chain)

Comment: @R.L I don't think that's possible at the moment...

Comment: @vsfDawg im mostly trying to see if it is possible in general on any version of Eclipse

Comment: @deHaar fair enough, i will keep it open and see if some people know some trick that could allow it :/

Comment: @R.L sure, I would do so, too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it in Eclipse 3.6 following [this post on the opposite problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172937/how-to-indent-the-fluent-interface-pattern-correctly-with-eclipse?rq=1):

in the formatter profile (preference>search formatter):

- in Line Wrapping>Function Calls>Qualified invocation: set "Indentation policy" to "Default indentation"
- in Line Wrapping>Default indentation for wrapped lines set to 0
- check all other settings to not use default indentation

but this solution is a bit dirty as it make use of the default indentation parameter for itself